# Cannot compile TRAP library: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘long int’)

Tags: c++

I've been trying to install a c++ module called TRAP ( http://trap.molgen.mpg.de/cgi-bin/download.cgi), but I face some errors that I can't understand yet,.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 with root prev. and I tried to make all the release file downloaded with the TRAP module .. unfortunately I cant use the R version as I need the C++ module as one of the dependencies of another .pl script

here i copy the return of "make all" command:

```
root@adwy-VB:/home/adwy/Downloads/ANNOTATE-3.04.01/Release# make all
Building file: ../read_matrix.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"read_matrix.d" -MT"read_matrix.d" -o"read_matrix.o" "../read_matrix.cpp"
../read_matrix.cpp: In function ‘void read_matrix_file(char*)’:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:44: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘long int’)
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                            ^
../read_matrix.cpp:75:44: note: candidate: ‘operator!=(int, long int)’ <built-in>
../read_matrix.cpp:75:44: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘int’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/postypes.h:227:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _StateT> bool std::operator!=(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)’
  227 |     operator!=(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/postypes.h:227:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:461:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)’
  461 |     operator!=(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:461:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:337:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)’
  337 |     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:337:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:375:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
  375 |     operator!=(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:375:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1151:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
 1151 |     operator!=(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1151:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1157:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator!=(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)’
 1157 |     operator!=(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1157:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:174:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator!=(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)’
  174 |     operator!=(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:174:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6188:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)’
 6188 |     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6188:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6201:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)’
 6201 |     operator!=(const _CharT* __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6201:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::basic_istream<char>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6213:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)’
 6213 |     operator!=(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6213:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:319:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator!=(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)’
  319 |   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:319:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘const std::error_code&’
  319 |   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:323:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator!=(const std::error_code&, const std::error_condition&)’
  323 |   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:323:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘const std::error_code&’
  323 |   operator!=(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:327:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator!=(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_code&)’
  327 |   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:327:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘const std::error_condition&’
  327 |   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:331:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator!=(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)’
  331 |   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:331:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘const std::error_condition&’
  331 |   operator!=(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_facets.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/fstream:38,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:214:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator!=(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)’
  214 |     operator!=(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:214:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:67,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1912:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)’
 1912 |     operator!=(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1912:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/map:61,
                 from ../matrix.h:9,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/array:257:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> bool std::operator!=(const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)’
  257 |     operator!=(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/array:257:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/map:61,
                 from ../matrix.h:9,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1445:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator!=(const std::tuple<_Tps ...>&, const std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&)’
 1445 |     operator!=(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1445:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::tuple<_Tps ...>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/map:61,
                 from ../matrix.h:9,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:1479:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)’
 1479 |     operator!=(const map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:1479:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/map:62,
                 from ../matrix.h:9,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_multimap.h:1143:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator!=(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)’
 1143 |     operator!=(const multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_multimap.h:1143:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/strings.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:432,
                 from ../read_matrix.cpp:8:
../read_matrix.cpp:75:46: note:   ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ is not derived from ‘const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>’
   75 |   while(matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n')!=NULL){
      |                                              ^~~~
make: *** [subdir.mk:35: read_matrix.o] Error 1
```

Comment: `matfile.getline` returns `matfile` which is an `istream`. You cannot compare or convert an `istream` to a number. File a bug with whoever wrote this code.

Comment: You *might* be able to get the code to compile by explicitly setting the compiler options to `-std=c++-03`, or by using an ancient compiler. More fundamentally, what do you want to use TRAP for? Judging by the code the application is clearly outdated. Are you sure it’s still the state of the art in the field? Unless you need to exactly reproduce some old results you’re probably better off using a more recently developed tool.

Comment: OT: Please don't use your root account unless you are doing system administration. It is easy to slip up and nuke your system or compromise your system by running/compiling untrusted code.

Comment: Thanks, I used root after getting a permission denied error trying to access one of the TRAP files and nano it, unfortunately I must use this module as a part of a perl algorithm published this year , and I need to use it in my work (https://gitlab.com/dianalab/adapt-cage). I face troubles since I started to use this algorithm it has a complex installation but holds a great potential when you read the paper .. I hope i can get this module installed, as already half of the perl algorithm is working fine, and I need TRAP now to continue the other half to get a full idea about the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just this one instance, you can replace that line by:

```
while (matfile.getline(mat_line,1000,'\n').good()) {
```

But there are bound to be other problems.

Comment: this solved the NULL error bugging the make all command